# get all books from person

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, core-data

I am working with swift 4 for macOS and I have two core data entities (Person and Book)

I would like to request all books, wehre Person == Max.
With this code I can fetch all books:

```
let request = NSFetchRequest<Book>(entityName: "Book")
request.predicate = // 
request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "bookName", ascending: true)]
   do {
      let books = try context.fetch(request)
      print(books)
   } catch { }
```

But how I have to use the predicate to get only the Books, which are assigned to the Person with the name "Max" ?

Comment: Did you have a look at "Filtering Results" in https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/FetchingObjects.html in the Core Data Programming Guide? – And why do you create a `NSFetchRequest<Position>` for fetching Book objects?

Comment: i guess this document doesn't helps me. I now that I can use the predicate like this: `request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "bookName = %@", "MyBook")` But I have to know how the predicate have to look for getting the assign person which is in relationship to the books

Comment: Just follow the key paths, e.g. `NSPredicate(format: "person.name = %@", "Max")`

Comment: How do I know which key path I should to use? I tried your code with `person.firstName` and I get: `CoreData: error: exception handling request: <NSSQLFetchRequestContext: 0x60400018a4f0> , keypath person.firstName not found in entity <NSSQLEntity Book id=6> with userInfo of (null)`
`

Comment: Please show how your entities are defined, and what properties and relationships they have, otherwise we can only guess. – Why does the error message is about a "Position" entity again if you created a fetch request for "Book"?

Comment: There is no "Position" in my error message? Entity Person: Attributes (firstName, secondName) | Entity Book: Attributes (bookName, Date).
Relation ship in Entity Person: relationship "books" | Destination "Book" | Inverse: "person". Relation ship in Entity Book: relationship "person" | Destination "Person" | Inverse: "books".

Comment: There was before your edited the comment :) – Why don't you add the relevant information to the question itself? – If Book has a relationship "person" to Person, and Person has an attribute "firstName", then `NSPredicate(format: "person. firstName = %@", "Max")` should work.

Comment: you are right - it works ! :) can you write an answer. than i can mark it as a correct answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- *Books* has a to-one relationship "person" to *Person,* and
- *Person* has a property "firstName".

So "person.firstName" is a key path from a book to the first name of
its owning person, and the predicate you are looking for is

```
NSPredicate(format: "person.firstName = %@", "Max")
```